# Unable to read an InputStream even though the file exists

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, inputstream

In my package `com.foo.bar`, I have two files, `Config.java` and `config.properties`. At the top of `Config`, I'm trying to read `config.properties` and set some internal variables:

```
public class Config
{
    public static String foo;
    public static String bar;
    static
    {
        try
        {
            System.out.println("Loading");
            InputStream is =     Config.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("config.properties");
            System.out.println("stream: " +  is );

            Properties props = new Properties();
            props.load(is);

            foo = props.getProperty("foo");
            bar = props.getProperty("bar");

            is.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    //snip...
}
```

Despite `config.properties` file existing in the same package, I get this output:

```
Loading
stream: null
```

And then a `NullPointerException` on the line `props.load(is)`.

What am I doing wrong? From some googling, it seems that I'm using the correct method for reading the file. Is it because I'm doing this in a static block, that I'm having this issue?

Comment: @Nisha `Config` is not a keyword, and `this.class` is not legal Java. What are you talking about?

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing this line

```
InputStream is =     Config.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("config.properties");
```

With this

```
InputStream is =  Config.class.getResourceAsStream("config.properties");
```

I hope it works :)

Comment: @vkg You were on the right track the first time. Adding getClass() was definitely wrong though. I suspect the file isn't where he thinks it is.

Comment: I just tested it and it works. I tested it exactly in a static block as you have. The answer is now what I originally posted.

Comment: @ClickUpvote It works as long as the file is in the right place. Clearly it isn't in your case.

Answer (score 2):

Replace this:

```
InputStream is =     Config.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("config.properties");
```

With this:

```
InputStream is =  Config.class.getResourceAsStream("config.properties");
```

This assumes that the `Config` .*class* file and the .properties are in the same directory at runtime of course, i.e. that the .properties file has been deployed. Having it in the same directory as the source file isn't necessarily a guarantee of that.